# Hostile Takeover Of Minted Coin In Crowdsale

Tags: security, crowdsale, mint

I am querying the warning on new crowd sales where minted tokens are made as per this guide: https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale which reads as follows:

> Once you published the crowdsale contract, get its address and go into your Token Contract to execute a Change Ownership function. This will allow your crowdsale to call the Mint Token function as much as it wants.
>
> Warning: This opens you to the danger of hostile takeover. At any
> point during the crowdsale anyone who donates more than the amount
> already raised will be able to control the whole pie and steal it.
> There are many strategies to prevent that, but implementing will be
> left as an exercise to the reader:
>
> Modify the crowdsale such that when a token is bought, also send the
> same quantity of tokens to the founder's account so that they always
> control 50% of the project Modify the Organization to create a veto
> power to some trusted third party that could stop any hostile proposal
> Modify the token to allow a central trusted party to freeze token
> accounts, so as to require a verification that there isn't any single
> entity controlling a majority of them

Am I correct in understanding that the reason behind this is based on the assumption that a DAO will have by default a 50% majority vote to alter the DAO constitution?

Comment: You are correct in your assumption.

Comment: Therefore a constitution requiring 99% consensus (where I retained control of say 2%) would provide protection, as would having no dao, just tokens & crowdsale contract (not sure if the second is possible)?

Comment: Correct - in theory - but you would need to define a consensus model in such a way that does not include inactive token holders, who don't ever vote, in the calculations. Else nothing will ever get passed. This could allow a whale (in certain edge cases) the ability to do a hostile take over. 

A DAO is not required - and most projects do not have a DAO. This would totally prevent a take over from happening.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Makes sense in theory now. Off to test!